# How to access the bot deployed from Microsoft Samples (bot-builder-samples)

Tags: botframework

I have created bots using the azure portal, which auto creates a bot app resource in azure. When I click on this resource via the portal, I can access the bot by opening the chat window and can try out the bot.

I also created bot using visual studio, published it to the azure web and then configured a 'bot channels registration' bot to use this published bot.

All good so far.

Now I am trying to go through the ready made Microsoft examples from: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-samples?view=azure-bot-service-3.0

I opened the "Create new conversation" link from the above website (https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/core-CreateNewConversation). I scroll down and click on "Deploy to Azure" button and the deploy is successful. How do I access the bot now?

I have tried creating the 'bot channels registration' bot and setting the messaging endpoint to the https://DeployedExampleAzureWebsiteLink/api/messages. Now, when I go into this azure resource, and into the test chat window, my message does not get delivered to the bot, and same issue upon retry aswell.

How do I access this bot please?

Comment: Make sure the MicrosoftAppId and MicrosoftAppPassword from the 'bot channels registration' are in the App Settings of the CreateNewConversation web app (or in the web.config file would also work).

Comment: Hi @EricDahlvang, done this, but then when I load the 'Test in Web Chat', and send a message, it says 'couldn't send retry'.

Answer (score 0):

When you click deploy to Azure you get an option to fill out the Microsoft App Id and Password. 
[image: Deploy to Azure]

You are supposed to enter the same App Id and Password you gave while registering the Bot in the Bot channel registration

Comment: I have tried this, but then when I load the 'Test in Web Chat', and send a message, it says 'couldn't send retry'.

Comment: @variable, there is an issue in how the project is built when using the Deploy to Azure process. For now, please use a bot template or clone a project from a BotBuilder repository to build a new bot in Visual Studio.

Comment: Hello @StevenKanberg, sorry I did not understand your comment, kindly can you clarify.

Comment: @variable, you have two options for creating a bot: install the VS bot templates or clone the BotBuilder GitHub repository and build a bot using the samples located there, also in VS.